# Error E0201 when implementing foreign trait for local type with parameter

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to add the `C` type parameter to this code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df492f20e0555cfc201ac49d0dfb3fd0)):

```
use std::ops::Index;

struct ConnectionHandle(usize);
struct Connection<C>(C);

impl<C> Index<ConnectionHandle> for Vec<Connection<C>> {
    type Output = Connection<C>;
    fn index(&self, ch: ConnectionHandle) -> &Self::Output {
        &self[ch.0]
    }
}
```

But doing so causes this error message:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `C` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g. `MyStruct<C>`)
 --> src/lib.rs:6:1
  |
6 | impl<C> Index<ConnectionHandle> for Vec<Connection<C>> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type parameter `C` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
  |
  = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

Why isn't this allowed? `Connection` is local, so per the explanation for `E0201` it seems like this should not result in orphans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Vec<Connection<C>>` isn't considered a local type, because `Vec` isn't local (and isn't [fundamental](http://aturon.github.io/2017/02/06/specialization-and-coherence/#the-fundamental-attribute)).

[RFC 2451](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2451-re-rebalancing-coherence.md) will make it legal, however. [An implementation was merged](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/56145) on January 4th, so it's not in stable yet, but it works with a recent nightly if the `re_rebalance_coherence` feature is enabled.