# Implementing a foreign trait for a local generic type

Tags: rust

I'm attempting to implement a trait from crate A for a trait from crate B using static dispatch. I'm wrapping the foreign trait, but am having trouble with the `impl<T>` line:

```
extern crate a;
extern crate b;

pub trait C: a::A {}

impl<T: C> b::B for T {}
```

**The end result I am looking for is implementing `b::B` for implementors of trait `C`, using static dispatch.**

I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<T>`)
 --> c/src/lib.rs:3:1
  |
3 | impl<T: C> b::B for T {}
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
  |
  = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

I'm able to get around this by using dynamic dispatch — `impl b::B for dyn C` — but want to accomplish this with static dispatch.

I've already tried:

- [Error E0201 when implementing foreign trait for local type with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400991/error-e0201-when-implementing-foreign-trait-for-local-type-with-parameter) — I'm not trying to implement a trait for `Vec`, but my own type
- [I implemented a trait for another trait but cannot call methods from both traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256519/i-implemented-a-trait-for-another-trait-but-cannot-call-methods-from-both-traits) — The types don't conflict
- [The trait cannot be made into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116984/the-trait-cannot-be-made-into-an-object) — I want to use static dispatch

Comment: You cannot do that: `B` isn't your trait, and your implementor is generic, so it can be external too.

Comment: Is that the case even though the type constraint on the generic is for my own trait `C`?

Comment: You can write `impl C for i32`, for example: that would imply that you try to implement a foreign trait for a foreign type while writing `impl<T: C> b::B for T`. Your "trick" doesn't bypass the orphan rules.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios I see. How is this different from the dynamic dispatch example I showed in my answer (`impl b::B for dyn C`)? The argument sounds the same for both, but the latter compiles without error. **`C` is not a foreign type AFAIK**.

Comment: Because `C` is your trait, so you own `dyn C`. The implementer and implementor cannot be both foreign. As soon as you own one of them, you're ok.

Comment: Okay, so we agree that `C` is not a foreign type. How would I statically implement `b::B` for `C`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200966/discussion-between-french-boiethios-and-kellen).

Comment: FYI, the current behavior is unwanted and will be corrected one day: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2451-re-rebalancing-coherence.md

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own)

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do is wrapping the foreign type in a `struct` (as opposed to introducing a new `trait` deriving from the foreign one):

```rust
extern crate a;
extern crate b;

pub struct C<T: a::A> {
    pub t: T,
}

impl<T: a::A> b::B for C<T> {}
```

This, however, sometimes requires some boilerplate to convert between `C` and the "normal" type.

This is sometimes called "NewType pattern" (as in https://github.com/Ixrec/rust-orphan-rules).